The four descriptions of the world as a reference to the four galuyos
The Torah recounts the state of the world just after G-d created heaven and earth (Bereishis 1:2):

And the earth was without form and void; and darkness was on the face
of the deep. And a wind from G-d moved over the surface of the waters.

The Midrash teaches us that when we read "four", it refers to the four galuyos, e.g. Bavel, Paras-Media, Yavan, Edom-Yishmael. The Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah 2:4) expounds on the posuk in Bereishis as follows:

“The earth was emptiness” – this is the Babylonian kingdom, as it is stated: “I have seen the land, and behold, it was emptiness and disorder” (Jeremiah 4:23). “And disorder [vavohu]” – this is the Median kingdom, [as it is stated:] “They hastened [vayavhilu] to bring Haman” (Esther 6:14). “And darkness”– this is the Greek kingdom, which darkened Israel’s eyes with their edicts, as they used to say to them: ‘Write on the horn of a bull that you have no portion in the God of Israel.’ “Upon the face of the depths” – this is the evil kingdom [Edom], which cannot be calculated, like the depths; just as the depths cannot be calculated, so is it with [the wickedness of] the wicked.

The Midrash connects the different descriptions of that specific malchus to a word in pesukim elsewhere in the Torah. However, I have trouble understanding why especially these pesukim are chosen when talking about the four galuyos - the four malchuyos.
The only thing, understandable for me, I found was in the sefer Peninei Ohr (Parshas Bereishis, p. 129), by the Or HaChaim Hakadosh:

The term bohu also hints at the subsequent exile, the Babylonian exile, referred to as bohu because the Aramaic translation of bohu is “emptiness” or “void.” Concerning the Babylonian exile, it is written in Yirmiyahu 51:34, "Nebuchadnezzar, king of Babylon, has devoured me… he has made me an empty vessel."

Are there any seforim, commentaries of articles that explain why these four descriptions of the state of the world after creating, before G-d created light are being connected to these pesukim?

As we learn from Rashi on Bereshis 1:1 and Bereshis Rabba 1:4, that the world was created bereishis, in the merit of reishis, i.e. Israel among the nations. Just as the first produce is sacred so is Israel, G-d's sacred nation. Yet, while we are the very purpose for which the world was created, in the next breath the Torah foreshadows the trials and tribulations we must endure throughout our history. The Divine Plan for human destiny is thereby framed at the outset by the verses Bereshis 1:1-2, from day One to the End of Days.
The commentary Yefeh To'ar (1), which views the verse Bereshis 1:2 as a remez to the 4 kingdoms explains the idea of Creation with the following excerpt:

The final point of Creation is the time of moshiyach, when the world gets settles in peace, and be filled with knowledge, and everyone will speak in the name of Hashem. Hashem did not refrain from creating the world as He conceived the idea of 4 kingdoms, despite the fact that multitude of their sinful acts and variants of faith were rebellion to His Honor. Hashem knows the final end, and because of it everything perfomed for our forefathers from the time of their redemption from Egypt and building the Temple - is an afront to His final goal, and so in the end it was all destroyed as if He acted for naught.
And His answer was that everything was due to the nature of the matter. The completeness of the entire human race was withheld from others for a long time, because the nature of their creation did not accept it from its beginning. For this it took a long time with many tests and trials and rebukes from several prophets and many troubles in bitter and difficult revelations. After that the redeemed (Jewish) people came out clean as pure and refined silver and returned to Hashem with all their heart and with all their soul. Thus, they knew faithfully that there was no truth and rejected all the kinds of deceptions, which only served to turn away people from from Hashem. Yes, they were ashamed and deceived by their deeds and recognized that there was no other remedy but to seek refuge under His wings. Thus, at the end they will come to Hashem in a covenant of peace (as granted to Pinchas) which will never be broken.

The idea of four kingdoms can schematically be represented by the 4 letters of the dreidel (theme 58 in (2) and (3), also Bnei Yisaschar) or in the word גֹשְנָה - the place of the first exile in Mitzrayim, where נ - nefesh, ג - guf, ש - sekhel, and ה - hakol or neshamah. Every exile among the nations sought to target the Jewish nation in different ways. Galus Bavel destroyed the First Temple, rendering it impossible for the Jews to perfect their souls (nefesh) through sacrifices (see Vayikra 2:1). The Persian/Median exile threatened our physical existence (guf) because of Haman's plot. The Greeks sought to supplant our knowledge base sekhel with their own, and when they could not win by intellectual superiority, they attempted to suppress the study of Torah. Finally Edom/Rome attacked us in every way (hakol). The Gematria of the word משיח is 358 = ג+נ+ה+ש. Thus the the Messianic king will be able to overcome hakol. Alternatively, the final teshuvah and overcoming of each of the kingdoms would allow the neshamah of the person enlighten his/her guf, nefesh and sekhel.

The midrash connects each of galuyos using similar words.
The verse Yirmiyahu 4:23 speaks of the prophetic vision of the prophet Yirmiyahu, of what was going to happen to Eretz Yisrael as a result of the conquest by Nevukhodnetzar king of Bavel. The army of Bavel would exile the people, destroy the Temple, and make the land empty and desolate (תֹ֖הוּ וָבֹ֑הוּ), same words as in Bereshis 1:2. (In the language of Kabbala, the exile targeted the nefesh of the Jewish people, as being uprooted from their land and subject to an environment of a different country).

The verse Esther 6:14 speaks how providentially the Persian king's eunuchs came in the middle of the argument between Haman and Zeresh and hurriedly (וַיַּבְהִ֙לוּ֙, i.e. astonished him) rushed Haman to Esther's banquet. The word וַיַּבְהִ֙לוּ֙ has root בהל - shock, astonish, which is similar to the word ּבֹּהו - astonishingly empty as pointed by Matanos Kehuna.
Additional the connection here can be coming via the verse Tehilim 30:8:

for You, O LORD, when You were pleased, made [me] firm as a mighty mountain. When You hid (הִסְתַּ֥רְתָּ) Your face, I was terrified (נִבְהָֽל).

I.e. just like the created אֶרֶץ was called בֹּהוּ in Bereshis 1:2 because it was void of רוּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים, so is a person who is נִבְהָֽל because s/he experiences the הסתר פנים של השם.
To understand the language of Kabbala, Rashi explains, that Harvonah overheard the conversation between Haman and Zeresh, where Haman expressed a wish to convince the king for the second time to hang Mordechai, ... and from here Harvonah knew why Haman ordered building the gallows. As we understand, the gallows is made to destroy the body.

The quote about the Greek Kingdom seems cryptic. For direct answer, one can use Yerushalmi Chagiga 2:2:4 stating

“Hillel and Menaḥem did not disagree. Menaḥem left and Shammai entered.” Where did he leave to? Some are saying, from behavior he left to behavior. But some are saying, he left against his face, he and eighty pairs of students of the Sages, wearing golden tirqe, whose faces became black like the rim of a clay pot, when they were told (by the Greeks), write on a bull’s horn that you have no part in the God of Israel.

In fact every Jew, who owned an ox was commanded to do so and publicize the heresy. Yefeh To'ar  states that the decree of the Greeks hints to the making of the Golden Calf which distanced us from Hashem. The reason why this answer works, comes from another midrash, Bamidbar Rabba 2:10, which talks about different directions symbolized by the camps in the desert. In particular,

North, from there darkness emerges to the world, and corresponding to it, the tribe of Dan. Why? It is because it brought darkness to the world with idol worship. Yerovam crafted two golden calves, and idol worship is darkness, as it is stated: “Their actions are in the dark (בְמַחְשָׁךְ֙)” (Isaiah 29:15). Yerovam circulated throughout Israel and it was only the tribe of Dan that accepted it from him, as it is stated: “The king consulted, and he crafted two golden calves…and he placed one in Dan” (I Kings 12:28–29). That is why the Holy One blessed be He commanded that Dan would encamp in the north. That is what is written: “The banner of the camp of Dan is to the north…” (Numbers 2:25). With it, the tribe of Asher, which illuminates the darkness, as it is stated: “And of Asher he said: Blessed…and he dips his foot in oil” (Deuteronomy 33:24). Likewise it says: “And those who encamp with it, the tribe of Asher” (Numbers 2:27). With it, Naphtali, who is filled with blessing in order to provide sustenance, just as it is written: “Naphtali, his desire is satisfied, [and full with the blessing of the Lord]” (Deuteronomy 33:23). Likewise it says: “and the tribe of Naphtali” (Numbers 2:29). “All those counted for the camp of Dan…they shall travel last by their banners (Numbers 2:31), as anyone who engages in idol worship goes backward and not forward. That is why it is stated: “The Lord founded the earth with wisdom, established the heavens with understanding”(Proverbs 3:19).

The key point is, the kingdom of Yavan (Greece) was forcing upon Jewish people avoda zara, with decrees to reject G-d of Israel, and the verse Isaiah 29:15 links avoda zara and darkness.
There are also circumstantial indications in other sources. For example, Megilas Taanis Adar

בח' בטבת נכתבה התורה יונית בימי תלמי המלך והחושך בא לעולם שלשת ימים.
On the 8th day of Teves the Torah was translated into Greek language in the days of king Ptolemy II and darkness (חושך) fell on the world for 3 days.

(On the kabbala level, the skin of the ox is used to make the batim for tefilin and parchments for Torah, tefilin, and mezuzos - items that symbolize the foundations of our faith and connection to the Torah. The fact that the Greeks forbade learning of the Torah - was a decree against our sekhel).
Interestingly, the mishna Mikvaos 9:2 also gives the answer which fits the language of the midrash. Among the things which prevent purification in the mikveh, the mishnah mentions טִיט הַיָּוֵן - miry, slimy clay and גֵץ יְוֵנִי - road clay, dirt:

What is meant by 'miry clay’? This means the clay in pits, for it is written: "He lifted me out of the miry pit, the slimy clay (מִטִּיט הַיָּוֵן)" (Psalms 40:3)... And "road-clay." These become like road-side pegs in these [kinds of clay] one may not immerse oneself nor immerse [other things] with them.

The root of the word יָּוֵן is the same as יון - the Hebrew name for Greece. Just like dirt prevents one to achieve purity, so did the Greek wisdom when applied to the wisdom of the Torah. For example, the Greeks denied that humans had ability to receive divine prophecy and that the laws of the Torah were divinely ordained. Such a view devalues the mitzvos and the Torah.

Regarding the kingdom of Edom it Yefeh To'ar states that it was great and tenthfold mighty. The Romans recruited conscripts into their army people from all nations of the world (Bereshis Rabba 42:4). In the army they would forget their native language and all become Romans so that there would not be distinction between people of the empire. Even with respect to religion, the Romans modified the beliefs of the conquered nations so that their faiths became variants of the single imperial cult. In this respect, the empire was similar to the deep waters, where one cannot see anything and distinguish one thing from another. As every nation has its own good or bad inclinations, the mix creates the confusion when anything of value for neshamah could easily be targeted.
Finally, regarding Moshiyach, the midrash uses Isaiah 11:2, which speaks about time of moshiyach with completion of the man, as Malbim explains:

And it rested upon him, the perfection will be in three things,
a. The perfections that depend on the fact that he has thinking nefesh, with strength, chokhmah, and binah. The chokhmah will be passed by tradition from the rabbis, and binah developing distinctions in matter by means of comparisons.
b. the perfection of him as a man, which includes the perfection in ability to give advice ('eitzah) and ability of might (g'vurah, i.e. guf). The power of advice as he will contemplate in every matter tenthfold. The power of might will come from completion of his physical development.
c. The perfections that depends on the fact that he is a holy, noble soul from on high whose elevation is higher than the thinking nefesh, and the perfection of this soul depends on whether he will have the knowledge of God, that is, to know true opinions in the truth of God, His providence and His ways. Such level was achieved by the prophets who communicated these truths in prophecy. And let him have a spirit of fear of God, for knowledge without fear is nothing, and likewise with fear without knowledge one does not know whom he is to fear. According to this, it means that these three perfections will be in the Messiah in completeness, sublime to the point of not being natural, but will relate to the Spirit of God, sublime from nature.


*Sources
(1) Commentary Yefeh To'ar on Midrash Bereshis Rabba 2:4 full edition by Zikhron Aharon
(2) Michoel Miller "Darkness and Destiny: The Four Empires in Midrash and Beyond" published by גליון in Lakewood, NJ, in 2011 (ph. 732-905-0091, FAX (732) 905-0081). It collects majority of the sources, if not all, regarding the 4 kingdoms and has a small commentary.
(3) Kuntres "Four Kingdoms" contains discussion about 4 kingdoms as a struggle for each of the nefesh, guf, sekhel, and neshamah with various sources from Chazal.

Can you summarize what it says, this is no more like a comment and I think there might be some valuable information there.

@Shmuel I will do later today. There are also kuntres based on writings of Luzzatto, Maharal and R' Hutner about the Four Kingdoms.

Wonderful. The more sources the better, and happier I will be with the answer :)

@Shmuel what do you think?

A Gute Voch! Thank you very much. I understand the first verse better now, and that it refers to Galus Bavel. However, the rest of the descriptions of the earth and that it refers to the other Galuyos, I have trouble with. With Esther, it seems to be a grammatically thing, but I don't see how it connects to each other. Are there meforshim to this Midrash that explain it?

@Shmuel other comments are Nezer haKodesh, Rabbeinu Bachya (not much), Maharzo, Nechmad LeMareh, Yedei Moshe (alll commentators say something). Regarding grammar of the verse in Esther,  Matnos Kehuna states "Bohu and Behalah - one thing". In Artscroll they translate בהו - astonishingly empty, similar to בהל - to shock, astonish.

Thanks. Unfortunately I still don't understand the rest of the references. Would you maybe be able to explain them (maybe using different meforshim)? That would be much appreciated and the answer will be rewarded  :)

@Shmuel I think I found a satisfactory answer for Galut Yavan. Tell me what you think. Thank you. Happy Chanukkah!

Thank you very much for the hard work. I need to delve into it and get back to you :) Chag Chanukah Sameach!

Yes wonderful addition. Thanks! I still have problem, though, with understanding what the Midrash says about Yavan (Greece). It links וָבֹהוּ to וַיַּבְהִלוּ. The Yefeh To'ar explains that Greece wanted to abolish faith. I don't see the connection with the posuk in Esther? Could you maybe help me out? What do the meforshim say about this?

@Shmuel Wait, we seem to have resolved fully Bavel and Yavan. The Paras is established using the Matnos Kehuna that the roots בהה and בהל are similar in that בהה is astonishingly empty and בהל is to astonish (destroy senses) by speedy rushing. Your last comment mixes Paras and Yavan.

Yes :) The first ones are decrypted now haha. However, I still don't undestand the relation between Paras and the words of the Matnos Kehunah: ויבהילו. בהו ובהלה אחת היא. Sure, these two words can share the same root, but why is Galus Paras(-Madai) linked to this very specific posuk? My apologies, this is the one Midrash I don't understand after a few years of studying, but we are getting there :)

Thanks though for also bringing "Among the things which prevent purification in the mikveh, the mishnah mentions טִיט הַיָּוֵן - miry, slimy clay and גֵץ יְוֵנִי - road clay, dirt" - this seems in relation to my other question where "the feet of clay" refer to Galus Yishmael.

@Shmuel yes, it fits although it does not have חשך.
